# Move sprite forever

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am trying to move sprite to the right when I press a button on the screen. However, when I try doing it I only have a solution to move the sprite to a certain point. So... I want the sprite to move to the right forever or until i do something else.

This is in Xcode using Swift in SpriteKit.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch : AnyObject in touches{

        let pointInTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let tappedNode = nodeAtPoint(pointInTouch)
        let tappeNodeName = tappedNode.name

        if tappeNodeName == "Btn"{

            player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

            let action = SKAction.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(400, 0), duration: 1)
            player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

            print("Touched!")                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to move the sprite to right forever but what should happen when it does exit the scene and is no longer visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply move your node to the right untill it does exist the scene

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var player: SKSpriteNode!

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let pointInTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let tappedNode = nodeAtPoint(pointInTouch)
        if tappedNode.name == "Btn"{
            let moveToRight = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width + player.frame.width, duration: 5)
            player.runAction(moveToRight)
        }

    }
}
```

### Update: constant speed

If you want the player to move with constant speed you can use this code.

As you can see I am calculating the duration using `space / speed`. You just need to find the best constant value for speed for your scenario.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var player: SKSpriteNode!

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
        let pointInTouch = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let tappedNode = nodeAtPoint(pointInTouch)


        let deltaX = self.frame.width + player.frame.width - player.position.x
        let speed: CGFloat = 10 // <-- change this to find the best value for you
        let duration: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(deltaX / speed)

        if tappedNode.name == "Btn"{
            let moveToRight = SKAction.moveByX(deltaX, y:0, duration: duration)
            player.runAction(moveToRight)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi man, just a curiosity, I've often seen guard let touch in touchesBegan , but thinking about it, if touchesBegan was fired, touches must have at least the first element, or I forget something? It might make sense for the other touches methods..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano: I agree, I've never found the `touches` Set to be empty. I use `guard` only because I like it but I think a force unwrap could be considered safe here.

Comment: @appzYourLife Thanks for the help! just one more question. If you want to move the sprite in a constant velocity. So the sprite will run at the same pace to the right of the screen even if he is placed on the left side of the screen or the in the middle for example.

Comment: @appzYourLife Great! Thank you so much for the help:)

Comment: only problem is you now lose the ability for multi touch, which the original code had